# Set different background color for all cells in a JTable Column, based on the String returned by the database Query

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I'm working on translating a project from gambas code language to Java.

Actually the first column of my `JTable`(where all the query results are shown) needs to be backgroud painted with diferent colours (yellow green cyan red) depending on the text read in the cell, the problem is that when I try to get the text (to be able to do a switch case for the 4 types of text to colours) or using any other function like => rs.getString or rs.getNString or rs.getBlob, it will never work throwing the error -> `java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set`.

I've been looking for this error for 2 days, and I can't find anything helpful other than I can't write two times the loop -> while(rs.next).

This is the class Database (db):

```
public class BaseDeDatos{

Connection conn; 

java.sql.Statement statement = null; 
java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = null; 
java.sql.ResultSet rs = null; 
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null; 
int columnsNumber = 0; 
int rowsNumber = 0; 

public BaseDeDatos() throws SQLException {
    this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("my driver"); 
}

public Connection getConn() {
    return conn;
}
}
```

This is into the MainView Class :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String sql ="";

                    bd.getConn();

                    bd.statement = bd.conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    bd.rs = bd.statement.executeQuery(sql);


                    // Removing Previous Data
                    while (jTable.getRowCount() > 0) {
                        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel()).removeRow(0);
                    }

                    bd.rsmd = bd.rs.getMetaData();

                    bd.columnsNumber = bd.rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();


                    jTable.setModel(resultSetToTableModel(bd.rs)); 
        // this line needs this -> import static net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel;




                    System.out.println(bd.rs); // CHECKING if the ResultSet Has it's Info Inside

                    String rsString = null;
        bd.rs.getString("1st COLUMN"); // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set.

        while (bd.rs.next()) {  // Doesen't matter if i delete the last line the program never goes inside this while (I'dont know why).
                        System.out.println("HELLOW");
                        String em =bd.rs.getString("Estado");
                        rsString = em.replace("Validado", ",");
                        System.out.println(rsString);
                        for(int j = 1; j < bd.columnsNumber; j++){
                            System.out.print(bd.rs.getString(j)+" ");
                            em = bd.rs.getString("Estado");
                            rsString = em.replace("Validado", ",");
                        }

                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }

                    setCustomDbColumns(); 
        // In this method i set up the width of the columns on my jTable nothing more special.

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }finally{
                    try{
                       if (bd.rs != null)
                         bd.rs.close();
                       if (bd.statement != null) 
                         bd.statement.close();
                       /*if (bd.conn != null) 
                         bd.conn.close();*/
                    }catch(SQLException e){}
                 }
```

The error pict
[image: The error pict]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach. Post code & error text, not _pictures_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement something like this

```
public void changeTable(JTable table,int column_index) { 
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column_index).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                        isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                if (!isSelected) {
                    int age = Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
     // you can set your own implementation here. As an example I 
     // have checked if the age is over 20 or not. According to the 
     // age return from the table column you get different background colors. 
                    int req_age = 20;
     // in your case req_age can be rs.getString("column_name"); or something
     // you need to check with..
                    if (age < req_age) {
                        c.setBackground(new Color(255, 101, 18));
                    } else {
                        c.setBackground(new Color(0, 204, 0));
                    }

                }
                return c;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Ex :**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> , it will never work throwing the error -> java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set.

```
jTable.setModel(resultSetToTableModel(bd.rs)); 
bd.rs.getString("1st COLUMN"); // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
```

Yes, the resutlSetToModel(...) method reads the data from the ResultSet, so you can't access the data in the ResultSet anymore.

If you want to access the data you can get the data from the TableModel.

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
Object data = model.getValueAt(0, 0);
```